# Spark lazy loading not working

Tags: apache-spark, lazy-loading

I am learning Spark. Below is the file content I created in HUE.

```
This is a first line
Spark, Spark, Spark, Spark, Spark 
HadoopExam, HadoopExam, HadoopExam
Google.com, HadoopExam
```

I create a RDD lines using lambda approach.

```
val Lines = line.filter(a => a.contains("HadoopExam"))
```

I then used *count() and first()* functions got results as *2 and HadoopExam, HadoopExam, HadoopExam* respectively.

Now I modified the file as below.

```
    Google.comHadoopExam
    This is a first line
    Spark, Spark, Spark, Spark, Spark 
    HadoopExam, HadoopExam, HadoopExam
    Google.com, HadoopExam
    HadoopExam
```

I didnot reload the RDD Lines.
However when I call functions count , the count shown is 3.
The first line is considred but the last line is not considered.
Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: could you post your code ?

Comment: @YuanJI 
 
Below is the code: {val line = sc.textFile("spark.txt"); val Lines = line .filter(a => a.contains("HadoopExam"))};